# How to download instagram page automatically with wget

Tags: linux, https, automation, instagram, wget

I want to download a personal instagram page automatically, I thought to use the command `wget` to download the entire page, but it doesn't work.

I set the header ( the same used by the browser ) and the cookie (take by cookie.txt extension) so the entire command line is:

`wget -x -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" --load-cookies cookies.txt -r "https://instagram.com/username"`

But the result is a white page with instagram logo.
Do you have other idea? Is there another way to achieve this? 
I think that the request is correct, maybe instagram uses dynamic request with javascript or similar and I'm following a bad way, but if it's true, when I open the page in the browser, this should execute javascript code. Is this correct?

Comment: Make that ~/cookies.txt, I suppose.  Btw, you could just use -U "Mozilla".

Comment: This might help: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: i tried to insert the path for the coockie.txt file but equal result.

Comment: Another question, if i open my browser by command line and then it save the page on a file? so i can examinate the page afterward. is it possible? can browser save page on a permanent memory?

Comment: The instagram api not permit to search by user but only by tag. So i need to find another way:
- open browser by command line, then go when it will be saved and analize it.
- try another mode with wget or similar

Comment: If you are looking for an app try this https://saveaxe.now.sh/ @michelecangeri

Answer (score 1):

`wget` is not a web browser. In particular, it doesn't understand JavaScript, and Instagram's user page has most of its content generated via JavaScript, so that's your first problem.

Your second problem is that [Instagram's bot policy](http://www.instagram.com/robots.txt) forbids the use of `wget`, and it's very conceivable that they have measures to detect wget even if you change the user agent - there are [companies which specialize in that](https://www.distilnetworks.com/).

Comment: I'm so curious about how detect the difference of packet between wget request and normal browser one. I think to abandon this way.

Comment: The link to policy page has no `wget` word, so that's probably outdated.

Comment: In this case, wget falls under `User-agent: *`.